# Youtube api v3 duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, youtube

I have problem getting duration from json. I defined `item.contentDetails.duration` but doesn't work every time (Error says  `undefined`). I don't know what is bad.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Samuell/hu5x1x2j/)

Comment: Can we see an example of your JSON?

Comment: @DavidWatts https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=AIzaSyBXuQPlhSo7Z7s2DS-9Ss-QbkFjagEKE6U&part=snippet,contentDetails

Comment: For single json it's working items[0].contentDetails.duration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems` only responses `contentDetails` with `videoId`, so you cannot retrieve  the duration attribute.

In your example, check again with [this json](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=6&playlistId=UUW02vQ7IbW3t_Gx64AaQEhQ&key=AIzaSyBXuQPlhSo7Z7s2DS-9Ss-QbkFjagEKE6U)